# How to handle router.back in Nextjs while using internationalisation?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, next-router

I'm trying to use the `router.back()`, but I'm also using i18n localization.

I start at the Home page which is `"localhost/"` and navigate to
`"localhost/auth/sign-in"`.

Now on changing the language (which has its specific route) `"localhost/firstLang/auth/sign-in"` and then changing again to another language `"localhost/secondLang/auth/sign-in"`.

When I want to navigate back using `router.back()` I want to be navigated to `"localhost/secondLang"` not to `"localhost/firstLang/auth/sign-in"`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How are you switching between languages? Could you please provide some code?